# Implicit Argument Passing in Python?

Tags: python

The code below is from hackermeter.com and I'm not sure what to think of it.  Is the variable i being passed implicitly to run() or does it expect more modification than just where it specifies?

```
import sys

def run():
   # Code here!

for i in range(int(sys.stdin.readline())):
   run()
```

Comment: Without knowing what `run` is supposed to *do*, it's useless to speculate on how (or whether) it has access to `i`.

Comment: Apparently not.  The answers below pointed out what the intention is.

Comment: The point is, if `run` doesn't use `i`, it doesn't matter. If `run` does use `i`, the code is poorly designed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd argue that this is a poor coding practice. The only reason `run()` has access to `i` is that `i` is global.

The following is arguably better as it will force the programmer to pass `i` into `run()` explicitly (if required):

```
import sys

def run():
   # Code here!

def main():
   for i in range(int(sys.stdin.readline())):
      run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: That must be what it is going on.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code in the question:

```
import sys

def run():
   # Code here!

for i in range(int(sys.stdin.readline())):
   run()
```

`i` is defined in global scope (that is at the top level of the module), and so is accessible inside `run`. This is because essentially only functions and classes introduce a new local scope, so an iteration variable is a normal variable of its enclosing scope.

If `run` does access `i`, this creates the potential for an error if `i` has not already been defined (e.g. if a conditional statement prevented the loop from being executed at all).